# Google Apps Script: Copying values from 1 spreadsheet to another if not the owner of the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this code to copy the data on one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet using a submit button:

```
`var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ss = source.getSheetByName("Gaming Report");
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:E39');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var tss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_H5zFaIuDhVbpX9hvuUOX9Hu_hpIlRyOy3hTnU1BjS0'); 
//replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Papamoa'); //replace with destination Sheet 
tab name
ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); //you will 
need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
```

This code works for me, but if someone I've shared the sheet with presses the submit button, it won't work, even if they have been shared with both spreadsheets.

Is there a way for this to work so it will copy the data no matter who presses the submit button?

Comment: Shared as an Editor or as a Viewer?

Comment: Hi - shared as an editor. Ideally this would work the best if the person pressing the submit button can send the data to a sheet that they are not shared with.